# Particle system from selected object

Tags: modifiers, particles

How do I create a particle system from an imported stl model and use that to fill the shell of another model? As you can see below, I want to fill the model to the right. There are two issues I am having. 1) The body is currently emitting the mini figurines rather that the internally contained collisions I was expecting. 2) A displaced modifier was applied to prevent the particles from moving beyond the skin, but if I could just set the collision boundary to the skin itself, that would be best. I read that applied modifiers are permanent, so I may need to redo this particle system on the original stl. Thank you!

[image]

[image]

(11/9/20) Tried Vertex paint mode and selecting the body under the Vertex Group --> Desnity, but it still had the same effect. I think the problem also is that internal face or area is not the source of the emitter. However, I found a tutorial **[here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pexD2XhncNY&t=13s&ab_channel=blatadej)** that shows how to fill a container by funneling the smaller objects via implemented physics engine. Will see if that works!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're looking for is the 'hair' particles system, if you want another object to cover the main object. When you add a particle system to an object, one of the first options should be to choose from Emission and Hair, switch it to hair. I'd recommend watching some tutorials for the same. If this is not what you were looking for, please reply.

Comment: I actually wanted to fill the bottom half shell of the sculpture with the mini figurines instead of having them covering the object. Thank you for your feedback though!

Comment: You can vertex-painting for that. Go into vertex painting mode, select the part which you think should have the mini-figures, go back to your particle system, scroll down until you see 'Vertex Groups' and for density, select the one that you just painted on.

Comment: I tried the vertex paint mode and selected the body, but the particles are still being emitted from the skin of th sculpture as shown above. You may check to see if it was set properly above. Thanks!

Comment: I can't tell based on the image, again, make sure you have it set to Hari and not Emission. And make sure that the right vertex group is selected. I'd love to help you out, can I contact you via Discord?